# Spring JDBC and Oracle Function issues

Tags: sql, oracle, spring, function

I am trying to execute an SQL Function using Spring JDBC.

My code is

```
SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplateRandOnline).withCatalogName("RATELIMIT_OWN").withFunctionName("Get_Logs");
RateLimitLogBean resultBean = null;
SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(P_YYYYMM, inputBean.getMonth(), Types.VARCHAR).addValue(P_NUMEC, inputBean.getNumec(), Types.INTEGER);
resultBean = caller.executeFunction(RateLimitLogBean.class, paramMap);
```

but when I run this code, I am getting below error

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call RATELIMIT_OWN.GET_LOGS()}]; 
>   SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; 
>   nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
>    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) at      org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:351) at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(SimpleJdbcCall.java:154)

I couldn't understand why it's throwing this error. For prepared statements we declare input and output params and compile them. But for functions, how can we compile when we are passing it as  SqlParamSource

Sql Function

```
FUNCTION RATELIMIT_OWN.Get_Logs ( p_yyyymm VARCHAR2, p_numec NUMBER )
```

This function returns records of type

```
TYPE RATELIMIT_OWN.LOG_RECORD AS OBJECT
   (EVENTID              VARCHAR2(15),
    MSG                    VARCHAR2(2000),
    CREATE_DATE      DATE);
```

I have debugged to Spring framework. What I found is, in

> org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.reconcileParameters method, I am getting this.metaDataProvider.getCallParameterMetaData() this arraylist with all values are null.

Any reason?

Comment: Can you share the prototype of your Sql Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the params of the function, something like that:

```
SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplateRandOnline)
                                           .withCatalogName("RATELIMIT_OWN")
                                           .withFunctionName("Get_Logs")
                                           .withReturnValue()
                                           .declareParameters(
                                              new SqlParameter("p_yyyymm",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
                                           .declareParameters(
                                              new SqlParameter("p_numec",java.sql.Types.INTEGER));
```

Comment: I have added like you said and I am still getting the same error

Comment: I have debugged to Spring framework. What I found is, in 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.reconcileParameters method, I am getting this.metaDataProvider.getCallParameterMetaData() this arraylist with all values are null. 

Any reason?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
```

To your SimpleJdbcCall.

Comment: This solution worked for me with or without the other solution.